# How do I check if a network drive is online/offline without my program hanging?

Tags: delphi, networking, delphi-xe7

I want to do some IO operations (reading files, listing folder content, etc) on a shared/network folder (`\\JoulePC\Test\`). If the folder is offline then the program will freeze for quite a while EVERY TIME I try to access it.

What I need to build is something like this:

> function DriveIsOnline(Path: string): Boolean;

The function should return an answer quickly (under 1 second). I would use the DriveIsOnline before performing any IO operations on that remove folder.

__

The API function `GetDriveType` will return 1 (which means 'The root path is invalid') if the drive is offline. Will it be logically correct to consider this answer ('1') as an indication that the drive is offline?

Comment: Do the read in a worker thread, or use overlapped I/O.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - But then I will have to wait anyway until the thread finishes :)

Comment: @RemyLebeau - oh... I could end the thread after 1 second...

Comment: Could try temporarily lowering the network timeout property if using Indy components.

Comment: @ThisGuy - I don't use Indy. I simply want to list all files in that folder.

Comment: @Altar: Don't kill the thread.  Let it timeout and terminate gracefully.  If you use overlapped I/O in a thread, you can specify a timeout on the I/O so the thread can terminate itself, while still not blocking your main thread.  However, how are you planning on enumerating the files? That is a different issue than simply checking the folder for its online status. File enumeration is synchronous. In that case, I would simply do the enumeration in a thread without timeouts, report results to the main thread as needed, and let the thread handle any errors reported if the folder is/goes offline.

Comment: You have to ask. If it times out, then perhaps it's offline. There's no other way.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - Sorry. I think didn't explained clearly what I want to achieve: I want to do some operations (doesn't matter what) on a network folder. If the folder is offline then the program will freeze for quite a while. What I need is something like this: function DriveIsOnline(Path): boolean. The function should return an answer quickly. I would use the DriveIsOnline before using the other IO operations on that remove folder.

Comment: There is really no point in checking ahead of time if it is offline or not.  It could go offline at any time, even in the middle of your operations.  You have to be prepared to handle that either way, so you may as well just start the operations unconditionally and let them fail if they need to.  As for the freeze, doing the operations in a worker thread would avoid freeing the rest of the app.

Comment: I agree with the second part but not with the first one. Why waiting soooo long at application start up (if the drive is offline) if I can check it (supposing it can be done) and move on in less than a second?